# Add a FULLTEXT index in Doctrine 2 using annotations?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, full-text-search

I know that Doctrine 2 doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes. I'm actually using a result set mapping and native queries to FULLTEXT search innodb tables (MySQL 5.6). But I still need to mark one or more entity fields as part of the index.

Is there any way to add the index using annotations? It seems that `@Index` annotation doesn't specify the type of...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to [DDC-3014](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3781) in the issue tracker of Doctrine, the possibility to specify full-text indices using annotations was implemented on April 14 and will be available in release 2.5. If you don't like to wait, you could try to use the unstable, development version or to backport [the commit](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/commit/3a1e24e6801961128c27104919050d40d745030b)  implementing the feature.

Here is a usage example:

```php
/**
* @Entity
* @Table(indexes={@Index(columns={"content"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
*/
class Comment
{
    /**
    * @Column(type="text")
    */
    private $content;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly with doctrine/orm dev-master, thanks. Unfortunately Doctrine extensions does not work yet with Doctrine 2.5, so I can't use it yet. See this issue (it's about Sylius, but refers to the Tree behaviour with doctrine/orm > 2.4.2): https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/1325

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how to make a fulltext index with the yaml mapping driver.

```
Doctrine\Tests\ORM\Mapping\Comment:
    type: entity
    fields:
        content:
            type: text
    indexes:
        xy_fulltext:
            columns: ["name", "content", "keywords"]
            flags: fulltext
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Doctrine 2.9 using PHP 8 attributes:

```
<?php
#[ORM\Index(columns: ['name'], name: 'name_idx', flags: ['fulltext'])]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ItemRepository::class)]
class Item {
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private string $name;
}
```

Source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/attributes-reference.html#attrref_index